# Can I use AWS CLI to add tags to all processing jobs matching a certain regex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I have close to 100 processing jobs to which I want to add certain tags. I've found commands that you can use to tag one resource with a list of tags. Is there any way I can do this for multiple jobs? Through CLI or through python+boto?

Comment: What is a "processing job"?

Comment: It's like a training job, except that you can use it to preprocess/analyze/ do anything else with data apart from training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI`'s method `tag_resources()`.
This is used to apply one or more tags to the specified list of resources.

References:

1. [Tag Resources using boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.tag_resources)
2. [UnTag Resources using boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Client.untag_resources)

Comment: I used the sagemaker boto3 client to fetch all the processing jobs matching a certain regex, and then used that with the tag resources client. Thanks for the answer!